# LoRa HAT communication module doesn't send anything

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, communication, raspberry-pi4, lora

I'm working on a long-range communication system, and I need help. I can't use GSM, WIFI, etc. I am testing a LoRa Raspberry Pi shield, and I bought [this](https://www.waveshare.com/sx1262-868m-lora-hat.htm), and I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SX1262_868M_LoRa_HAT). Of course I have tested other tutorials, like [this](https://www.spotpear.com/index/study/detail/id/244.html), [this lib](https://github.com/ehong-tl/micropySX126X), and others. None of them worked.

I have bought another 2 modules, because maybe my first purchase didn't work, but this wasn't the problem. (I didn't read any data from the other device in receiver module, but in the sender the TX LED was activated).

I want to communicate up to 30km (with a direct view), and I want to send data about 100 kbit per second.

So if you find another way to solve this problem (e.g. better tutorial), I will be grateful. I'm open to any other solution and idea. Thanks for your help.

*(If this isn't the best forum for this, I'm sorry)*

Comment: Try raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. And you need to be much more specific than "None of them worked".

Comment: Andreas Spieß on YouTube has many excellent LoRa tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adhWIo-7gr4&t=119s

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the eByte module on the RPi shield. What module are you using on the other end? The same? Or something else? If it's the same, it *should* work. But if you are using a non-eByte, regular LoRa module, like an SX1276 or SX1262 attached to an ESP32, forget about it, it won't work. It turns out that the "managed" eByte modules, with a -T- in their name, don't do LoRa, really, but FSK/OOK. So if you are trying to communicate between a RPi shield and a regular LoRa module, you will grow old before it works.

As for 30 km, forget about it. Not with that equipment. And especially not at 100 kbs, lol.